# Spacing between firebase items

Tags: android, firebase

[I wanted to give a space between all the conversations so they don't stay like this together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8sYE.jpg)

I wanted to give a space between all the conversations so they don't get like this together and not be able to give a space between the conversations, can anyone see what it could be? or some code to give a space between the conversations.

there is a photo above showing how it is together with the conversations

chat_room

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#FFD700"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="ENVIAR" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msg_input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_send" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFD700">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Chat_Room

```js
public class Chat_Room  extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn_send_msg;
    private EditText input_msg;
    private TextView chat_conversation;

    private String user_name,room_name;
    private DatabaseReference root ;
    private String temp_key;

    private ScrollView mScrollView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_room);

        btn_send_msg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        input_msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg_input);
        chat_conversation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

        user_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name").toString();
        room_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("room_name").toString();
        setTitle(" CHAT DE CONVERSA ");

        root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(room_name);

        btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                temp_key = root.push().getKey();
                root.updateChildren(map);

                DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
                Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map2.put("name",user_name);
                map2.put("msg",input_msg.getText().toString());

                message_root.updateChildren(map2);

                mScrollView.fullScroll(mScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

                input_msg.setText("");

            }
        });



        root.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private String chat_msg,chat_user_name;

    private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

        while (i.hasNext()){

            chat_msg = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
            chat_user_name = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();

            chat_conversation.append(chat_user_name +" : "+chat_msg +" \n");


            mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mScrollView.fullScroll(mScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                }
            });

        }


    }
```

Comment: You can do this in two ways, either you can add padding to the container element like this, `android:layout_padding="8dp"` or you can add margins to all the elements like this, `android:layout_marginTop="20dp"`.

Comment: Hey Lucas. Have you tried Vaibhav Goyal's suggestion?

Comment: but where could i put it? scroolview?

Comment: I've tried but I can't